# passing a array of strings parameter from jenkins to powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have the following script

```
function dummy
{
    param([string[]] myArray)
    myArray | foreach {
         #do something with $_
    }
}
```

from powershell if I do the following everything is fine
    . ./myscript.ps1
    dummy 'val1','val2'

but i can't get this to work from jenkins with a global var I have defined

```
. ./myscript.ps1
dummy $env:myglobal
```

where  $env:myglobal = 'val1','val2'
it appears to be passing the following

```
dummy "'val1','val2'"
```

and the dummy treats it as a single string instead of a string array

Comment: I also tried dummy @($env:myglobal)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably oversimplifying, but basically environment variables are just strings (i.e. not arrays!).

What you'll need to do is parse the value using `-split` e.g.

```
function dummy {
    Param (
        [string[]]
        $myArray
    )

    Process {
        [array]$anotherArray = $myArray -split ","
        $anotherArray| ForEach-Object {
             #do something with $_
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll use the work around; unfortunate there isn't a real solution for the issue.  When passing from the command line it is also passing a string

Comment: dummy 'val1','val2' works when passing from the command line.  When it's passed from Jenkins it's treating the value as "'val1','val2'"  Notice the extra quotes.  This results in powershell treating the input as a string constant with a , instead of two strings